# Counting null as percentage

Tags: pandas

Is there a fast way to automatically generate the null percentage for each columns, and output as a table?

e.g., if a column has 40 row, with 10 null values, it will be 10/40

I use the following code but now work (no values shown):
[image]

Comment: `mean` has `skipna` param but if you column has `NaN` then the returned result will be `NaN`, it makes more sense to set `NaN` to `0` in this case so calling `fillna(0)` first so `df[col].fillna(0).mean()`

Comment: Did you try `df.mean(axis=1, skipna=False)`? or `df.fillna(0).mean(axis=1)`?

Comment: @Ednum, but that would calculate the mean values in the cell ?

Comment: No it calculates the mean for the row which is what you want isn't it? Also your statement *a column has 40 row* makes no sense, you mean a row with 40 columns or 40 elements of which 10 are `NaN`?

Comment: Why not `1 - df.count()/len(df.index)`. That'll give a series of column-wise null %?

Comment: Sorry are you trying to count the number of nan's per row? Sorry I misunderstood this, you can do `df.isnull().sum(axis=1)/len(df)`

Comment: @EdChum thanks, but it is per column

Comment: so you want `df.isnull().sum()/df.shape[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC then you can use `isnull` with `sum` and then divide by the number of rows:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,5], 'b':[np.NaN,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
df

Out[12]:
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  5.0  NaN

In [14]:    
df.isnull().sum()/df.shape[0]

Out[14]:
a    0.4
b    0.8
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `df.count()`

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  5.0  NaN

In [57]: 1 - df.count()/len(df.index)
Out[57]:
a    0.4
b    0.8
dtype: float64
```

Timings, `count` is decently faster than `isnull.sum()`

```
In [68]: df.shape
Out[68]: (50000, 2)

In [69]: %timeit 1 - df.count()/len(df.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 542 µs per loop

In [70]: %timeit  df.isnull().sum()/df.shape[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop
```